# generate PDF file similar as generated csv usin SQR report

Tags: sqr

I am using SQR people soft to generate a CSV file and i have generated the CSV file as per requirment.

I need to generated a pdf report similar as generated csv file using SQR.

Is there any direct command to generate pdf using CSV report?

I need to do this in a single SQR report.

for ex.

generate test.pdf from test12.csv

kindly suggest.

Comment: please let me know if any other work around available in SQR to generate the PDF.

Comment: You didn't give any details on how you generated the CSV report.  Did you use Write or did you use the command line flag?  In any case, there is no way to "generate" a PDF from a CSV via SQR.  Use Print to write your output and then set the command line flag -printer:pd to write to PDF.  Alternatively, if you already have the CSV, you can use Excel and do Save As then choose PDF as an option.  If you like either of those options, let me know and I can give you more details.

Comment: thanks! I am using write comand to generate the csv. i need to generate similar pdf as the csv. if u need the code of SQR for generate the csv file please let me know

Comment: Don't need the code.  Here's option 1: Try converting the CSV using Excel directly - load CSV into Excel, then issue the command File > Save As > and choose PDF from the "Save as Type" dropdown.  That should be the easiest.  Option 2 is to use the PRINT command in SQR instead of the write command and then when you run SQR, add this flag to the command line: -printer:pd    (include the dash at the start).  However, I think your first option is the easiest if you have at least Excel 2007 (I think)